# With a SmartThings system, what is the result of marking an alert as a false alarm?

Tags: smart-home, samsung-smartthings

We have a few SmartThings motion detectors and door sensors hooked up in our house. We don't have them connected to an alarm company or any sort of automatic emergency line but we do get notified when we have the house in away mode and one of the sensors is tripped.

The app gives you two options for dismissing the alert

1. dismiss
2. false alarm

We've been dismissing them because the alarms are correct - usually someone is in the house when both of our phones are away (most recently my mother-in-law who is visiting and we're still out for work).

Is there, at this point, a purpose for the "false alarm" response? What does marking an alert as a false alarm do?

Answer (score 5):

I found this quote:

> You will also have the option to check the box saying This was a false alarm. This is for internal tracking and helps us improve Smart Home Monitor.

This is from https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-gb/articles/205380154-Smart-Home-Monitor#Dismiss_Incident

So, false alarm mark is for internal use of SmartThings to make their service better.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for finding this info. I'm concerned that, without adequate documentation of how to use this check box, they'll be getting a lot of bad data, though. :(

Comment: To be continued in [meta discussion](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/is-it-wrong-to-give-a-little-piece-of-information-in-answer-if-no-other-is-avail).